# Get-ChildItem with wild chars in path without "Where"

Tags: windows, powershell, ps

I want to use wild characters in path passed to `Get-ChildItem`. So in example I want to use `C:\root\*\container` as a path parameter. But this searches only in 1 level below. If I would write `C:\root\*\*\container` then it would search 2 levels below only.

I try to do something like `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\root\*\container\vc$number" "*test*.exe" -Recurse`
and copy results into certain directory. If I search recursively in `C:\root` I find too many files. If I use path given in an example then I search only 1 level below, not recursively in all directories (that can be even 5 levels deep). I know I can use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\root\" "*test*.exe" -Recurse | Where { %_.FullName -like "container\vc$number" }
```

but I was wondering if I can skip using `Where`and use wild chars in path. Reason for that is I read paths from external file and some paths contain wild chars (as example above) and some don't. So I hope I don't have to write function that processes path and uses `Get-ChildItem` with / without `Where`

So in example I have

`C:\root\container\*test*.exe`, `C:\root\a\container\*test*.exe`, `C:\root\b\container\*test*.exe`, `C:\root\c\x\y\container\*test*.exe`, `C:\root\c\x\y\z\g\container\*test*.exe`

and so on. And with `C:\root\*\container` I want to find all of them

Comment: What about `-depth` parameter with `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh `-depth` doesn't do the trick because I don't want to restrict depth. So in example I have `C:\root\container\*test*.exe`, `C:\root\a\container\*test*.exe`, `C:\root\b\container\*test*.exe`, `C:\root\c\x\y\container\*test*.exe`, `C:\root\c\x\y\z\g\container\*test*.exe` and so on. And I want to find all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Childitem` has a parameter `Filter` which you can use to filter the results you want. In your case (as i understood) you want to get files in all the directories named "container".

First you have to get the path to these directories, then get the files inside as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\root" -filter "*container*" -recurse | Get-ChildItem
```

**Output**

```
C:\root\a\container\new.exe
C:\root\b\container\sample.exe
C:\root\c\x\y\z\g\container\anything.exe
```

**I used `.Fullname` at the end to get them displayed as above**